# how to get email address of friends using facebook api in asp.net using c#?

Tags: facebook

please any example then give me...dont give me reference site name or any facebook sdk site..because i used sdk for ASp.net and in friendlist class it show me only email hashes instead of any email address,so there is any other way to get friend email full email address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Facebook api has never and most likely will never expose friends email addresses.  If you want to do this just for your own account, Facebook gives you the option to [sync your friends & their email addresses with a Yahoo mail account](http://www.labnol.org/internet/export-email-addresses-from-facebook/12970/), but again this is a feature that is not available through any kind of API.